# Moving charges and steady current

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-current, magnetostatics

Steady currents generates a constant magnetic field-magnetostatic
Formally, this is $\frac{\partial \vec{J}}{\partial t}=\vec{0}$

Any currents steady or otherwise are due to the movement of point charges-electric charges.

> But how does the a moving point charge ties in with the fact that moving point charges cannot constitute a steady current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way one defines a current density J even though current is caused by discrete moving charges and should not have a continuous density.
We look at a macroscopic volumes over which the discrete nature of the current can be ignored but not so big so as to wash out any large scale variations.
In microscopic volumes moving charges don't constitute a steady current ,but over volumes containing thousands of atoms we can regard it a continuous current. In these volumes the average charge density does not change with time and that's what defines a steady current.